# Log Parser COM -iCheckpoint

Tags: parsing, logging, plugins, com, checkpoint

I have these Apache Tomcat logs which i'm looking to load into database. The current process is to load the logs the day after.

The aim is to incrementally load the log for the day at 12pm, 3pm and 6pm. I've had a look at the log parser help and online and have found the input parameter: iCheckPoint. However this parameter is not applicable to the COM plugin.

I'm looking to find out whether there is an implementation for the iCheckpoint parameter for custom plugin is available.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not. The implementation of the checkpoint itself depends heavily on the actual source of data; for example, if your COM plugin was reading from text files, then the checkpoint information would be the line number in each text file; on the other hand, if your COM plugin was reading from a SQL table, then the checkpoint info would be the last ID read. It's too source-specific to be "outsourced" to the host of the plugin (i.e. LogParser itself).